# Content disappear behind header's height?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Hello once again :) !

Can anyone accidently help me with this problem.
I saw very few sites before, but never bookmarked any of these.

If I have body background, fixed header and inner background, where the content is...
And if I want to scroll down to see more content/inner background, my image goes above header behind and I don't know how to make it to disappear behind headers top margin. Anyone can help me with this , please ?

Images:
Normal body background, fixed header and inner background below header
http://screensnapr.com/v/HbcNXA.png

Body background, fixed header and scrolled inner background below header, went above header's position.
http://screensnapr.com/v/TKVVuy.png

I know my English is not good enough to explain this... But let's say.

"Hey I am content background, I am standing below header and when someone scrolls me, I am disappearing at the start of header's position." :)

Thanks!

EDIT:
http://jsfiddle.net/WbtQd/

Scroll and you will notice what I want.

EDIT 2:
Seems like someone play with fiddle... Anyway, here is site example:
http://www.monofactor.com/portfolio/mcfc-auctions/

Except that my header have lets say: top: 50px;
So if we add on his site top: 50px; even he have same problem like me :)

http://snpr.cm/OrXCWa.png

EDIT 3:
http://snpr.cm/GNZaGd.png

Comment: Some CSS and HTML would be helpful for us to help answer this. Could you provide some?

Comment: im making on fiddle :) wait please!

Answer (score 0):

I; not sure if I understood you completely. You mean that whenever you scroll your page, the main body passes under the header. probably this is because the header is fixed. You can try to make your main body div scrollable. This way, whenever you scroll down, only this specific div will scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what your trying to achieve exactly, but zindex in css can make items appear above others. Add this to the header css code:

```
#yourheaderid {
  z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: Oh :( I posted even fiddle...

My header is fixed and background in body is fixed as well ... the only thing that is scrolling is another background of content which goes behind header as supposed but goes above it's edge. It should not be visible that it goes above the header size.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jsfiddle of how you should markup your fixed header and the css to go with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/LYT6V/

I'm assuming this is the result you were looking for?

Comment: Fiddle is buggy for me somehow... 
Anyway, I copied everything into my comp. and it doesnt seem to be fixed. (at least not what I wanted)